# Vaadin GridPro: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'localName' of undefined"

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I recently moved to Vaadin 14 and am now trying to use the `com.vaadin.flow.component.gridpro`.
If I now use `com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.ComponentRenderer<>` to render the row details, I get following error message(notification) when clicking on the generated details:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'localName' of undefined

While there aren't any Java Exceptions, Chromium has logged following:

```
client-FD21A18FF7B71…CC75CC.cache.js:198 TypeError: Cannot read property 'localName' of undefined

vaadin-grid-pro-inli…g-mixin.js?84ef:176 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localName' of undefined
at HTMLElement._isEditColumn (vaadin-grid-pro-inli…g-mixin.js?84ef:176)
at HTMLElement.eval (vaadin-grid-pro-inli…g-mixin.js?84ef:148)
```

I am aware, that this does not happen when using `com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid`instead of `com.vaadin.flow.component.gridpro.GridPro` but my question is how do I get rid of this error when using `GridPro`?

**Recreating my issue:**

Create a new Vaadin 14 project from archetype:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST -DgroupId=org.test -DartifactId=vaadin-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Change `MainView.java` to this:

```
// import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.gridpro.GridPro;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.ComponentRenderer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;


@Route
@PWA(name = "My Application", shortName = "My Application")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
       GridPro<Foo> grid = new GridPro<>();
       // Grid<Foo> grid = new Grid<>();
       grid.addColumn(Foo::getBar).setHeader("Bar");

       grid.setItemDetailsRenderer(
            new ComponentRenderer<>(s -> {
                VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
                layout.setSizeFull();
                Label label = new Label(s.getBar());
                layout.add(label);
                return layout;
            }));

       add(grid);
       grid.setItems(new Foo("Click me"));
    }

    private static class Foo {
        private String bar;

        private Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return bar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a bug in grid pro component. I would suggest to create a ticket at [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-pro-flow/issues)

Comment: @anasmi Thanks for the response. I guess I'll stick to the normal grid then